# How to change the column height and width dynamically in PDF file using iOS7?

Tags: pdf, ios7, multiple-columns

I have created a PDF file by referred from this link

http://www.raywenderlich.com/6818/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2

In this link they assigned fixed column height & width( `int rowHeight = 50;int columnWidth = 120;`) but what I need now is to dynamically change the column height and width.Is it possible?if possible how to do and explain me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either switch case or array concept here i used switch concept for the given example u can change the column Width values as u want in your program

```
-(void)drawTableAt:(CGPoint)origin
 withRowHeight:(int)rowHeight
   andRowCount:(int)numberOfRows
andColumnCount:(int)numberOfColumns

    {
    for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfRows; i++) {
    int newOrigin = origin.y + (rowHeight*i);
    CGPoint from = CGPointMake(origin.x, newOrigin);
    CGPoint to = CGPointMake(origin.x + 580, newOrigin);
    [self drawLineFromPoint:from toPoint:to];

}

for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            columnWidth=0;
            break;
        case 1:
            columnWidth=75;
            break;
        case 2:
            columnWidth=315;
            break;

        case 3:
            columnWidth=475;
            break;

        case 4:
            columnWidth=580;
            break;

    }
    int newOrigin = origin.x + (columnWidth);
    CGPoint from = CGPointMake(newOrigin, origin.y);
    CGPoint to = CGPointMake(newOrigin, origin.y +(numberOfRows*rowHeight));
    [self drawLineFromPoint:from toPoint:to];

}
    }
```